# Returning a list and a count in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I was asked this question the other day in a phone screen and I had trouble with it.  Suppose I have the following table.  This is a table of employees, and more than one employee can have the same supervisor.

```
+------------+--------------+------+
| Field      | Type         | Null |
+------------+--------------+------+
| name       | varchar(40)  | NO   |
| department | varchar(100) | NO   |
| supervisor | varchar(100) | NO   |
+------------+--------------+------+
```

What query would I write to return a list of supervisors and a count of how many employees have that supervisor?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use something like this (assuming your `supervisor` column is not a reference to another table)

```
select supervisor, count(name)
from employees
group by supervisor ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select supervisor, count(*) as cnt
from emp
group by supervisor
```

Answer (score 0):

That is called a "self join" and requires the use of table aliases.

```
SELECT a.*, COUNT(b.name) AS numsubs
  FROM employees AS a
  LEFT JOIN employees AS b
    ON a.name = b.supervisor
  GROUP BY b.supervisor
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do a row count grouped by supervisor:

```
SELECT supervisor, COUNT(*) as managed_employees_n 
FROM Employees  
GROUP BY supervisor
```

This works, assuming you have a hierarchy with 2 levels only: there's not a supervisors' supervisor.

In a real scenario those names must be transformed to IDs, otherwise grouping by name could lead to wrong results... what if you find yourself with two different supervisors both called "John Doe" ?